# django filter admin ModelForm values

Tags: python, django, admin

In admin page, when selecting `field_1` need to filter `field_2` by `field_1` value.

Code `random/models.py` :

```
from django.db import models
from app.models import ModelOne, ModelTwo

class RandomClass(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne)
    field_2 = models.ForeignKey(ModelTwo)
```

On admin page need to filter `field_2` values after `field_1` is selected.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

[Go Through this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

There is list_display and list_filter

Suppose if you want to get the value of Foreign Key Field that is mapping to other Table.

like this ..

```
def get_field_name_details(self):
        if(self.field_name):
            return "%s"%(self.field_name.user_first_name)
        else:
            return "Not Available"
```

**Note**
    in code `field_name` is Field in model which is `referencing` to other models using `Foreign Key`

And put this code in models as custom method as what you want to display and filter in Admin

And put this in `list_display` and `list_filter` of `Django` Admin Feature.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I answered not correctly. In admin form, I'll get 2 dropdowns, after I select `field_1` value I need to filter `field_2` values by selected `field_1` value